# Non-convergent rearrangement of the terms of a relatively convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, absolute-convergence

Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x_{n}}$ be a series in $\mathbb{C}$ that is conditionally convergent (i.e. convergent, but not absolutely). Show that there exists a bijection $\pi : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ so that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x_{ \pi (n)}}$ does not converge.
We are given these two facts:

1. Let $(x_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $x_{n}^{+}= \max \{ 0,x_{n} \}$ and $x_{n}^{-}= \max \{ 0,-x_{n} \}$. Then the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x_{n}}$ absolutely converges if and only if the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x_{n}^{+}}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x_{n}^{-}}$ both converge.
2. Let $(x_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $a_{n}=\Re(x_{n})$ and $b_{n}=\Im(x_{n})$. Then the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x_{n}}$ absolutely converges if and only if the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_{n}}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{b_{n}}$ both converge absolutely.

Is the following reasoning correct? We know that the new series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x_{ \pi (n)}}$ does not converge in $\mathbb{C}$. This implies that both $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_{n}}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{b_{n}}$ do not converge either. It then follows that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_{n}^{+}}$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_{n}^{-}}$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{b_{n}^{+}}$and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{b_{n}^{-}}$ are not convergent.
If this was correct so far, then how can I go on from this? Or is there a “better” solution to this problem?

Comment: @Masacroso: thanks, I edited it!

Comment: @GEdgar: yeah I see now that I wasn't thinking clearly...

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is not quite correct. The fact that $\sum x_{\pi(n)}$ does not converge means that *at least one*  of the two series
$$
\sum a_{\pi(n)} \qquad \mbox{ and }\qquad
\sum b_{\pi(n)}
$$
diverges (but *not necessarily both of them* diverge).

A simple proof might

(1) show that conditional convergence of a series $\sum x_n$ in ${\mathbb C}$ implies conditional convergence of at least one of the two series $\sum {\rm Re\,}x_n$, $\sum {\rm Im\,}x_n$ in ${\mathbb R}$ - and then

(2) appeal to [Riemann's theorem on conditionally convergent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).